# How I write a:hover::before in less file?

Tags: html, css, less

I have some `CSS` rules and just I need to write them in my `LESS CSS` file.

This is my `CSS` -

```
div.files a > div,
div.files a:before {
    transition: background-color 350ms;
}

div.files a:hover > div {
    background-color: #000;
}

div.files a:hover::before {
    background-color: #017BC6;
}
```

This is how I tried it in my less css file. But can't get it to work.

**UPDATE:**

```
> .files {
    margin-top: 18px;
    ....

    a {
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        .....

        &:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        &:before {
            background-color: #000;
            transition: background-color 350ms; 
            ....
        }

        &:hover {
            content: "";
            .block {
                background-color: #000;
            }

            &::before {
                background-color: #017BC6;
            }
        }


        .block {
            background-color: #017BC6;
            transition: background-color 350ms;
            ....

            .name {
                ....
            }

            .meta {
                ......

                &:after {
                    ....
                }

                .date {
                    ...
                }

                .format {
                    ...

                    &:before {
                        ...;
                    }                               
                }
            }    
        }
    }

    div {
        ......
    }
}
```

This is my `HTML` -

```
<div class="files">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="name">.......</div>
            <div class="meta">
                <div class="date">.....</div>
                <div class="format">....</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I am confusing how to write this kind of rules in less (`a:hover::before`).

Hope someone may help me out. 
Thank You.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong there other than the typo mate. Are you getting any error while compiling? *Edit:* And also the top level selector in the LESS code is different from your CSS selector.

Comment: can you elaborate this "And also the top level selector in the LESS code is different from your CSS selector"

Comment: @TNK `> .files` is different than what you have in the css (`div.files`). You also don't have `div.files a > div` in LESS

Comment: Judging by the code posted here, the CSS is looking for `div.files` meaning a div element with class as files whereas the LESS is looking for an element with class as files that is the direct child of another element. Ofcourse, they could still be same depending on the rest of the code, but just pointed out.

Comment: @Harry, `transition: background-color 350ms;` also not working for me..

Comment: @Harry, Check I updated my `LESS` and `HTML`..

Comment: check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jkEsF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59110/discussion-between-tnk-and-harry).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in the chat, there were a few corrections that needed to be made and they are as follows:

1. The typo in the `&::befor` had to be corrected to `&::before`.
2. The parent selector (the topmost one) had to be modified from `> .files` to `div.files` because we are looking to apply the styles to the `div` element with `class='files'` and its descendants.
3. The transition wasn't working initially because of nesting issues and the presence of `content: "";` within the `:hover` selector.

**Full code:**

```
html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div.files {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    counter-reset: file;
    a {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        padding: 4px 4px 4px 62px;
        text-decoration: none;
        counter-increment: file;
        & .block, &:before {
        transition: background-color 350ms;
        }
        &:hover {
              > div {
              background-color: #000;
              }
              &::before {
            background-color: #017BC6;
              }
        }
    }
    a:before {
        content: counter(file);
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        left: 2px;
        width: 68px;
        height: 68px;
        border: 5px solid #fff;
        background-color: #000;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 72px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    div {
        line-height: 1em;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
        a > div {
        padding: 14px 14px 14px 28px;
        background-color: #017BC6;
    }
        .name {
        margin: 0 0 14px 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .meta {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #bebfba;
        font-weight: bold;
                &:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
            }
    }
        .date {
        float: left;
    }
        .format {
        float: right;
                &:before {
            content: "Format | ";
            }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/vtcyw)

Answer (score 0):

if before and after element doesnot have content they not be visible at all

```
.x{
    &:before{content: '';}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
&::befor {
    background-color: #017BC6;
}
```

You've got a typo goin' on over here!

Should be

```
&::before {
    background-color: #017BC6;
}
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. Changed my answer to reflect it :)